# Applying .fadeIn() and .animate() at the same time

Tags: jquery

With this code, related image does not make de FadeIn effect and the animation at the same time. It firts fades, and when that has finished, it applyes animation. I need them to be done ant the same time:

```
$('.b4').fadeIn(2000);
$('.b4').animate({'right': '400px'}, 5000);
```

Other options I've tried without effect:

```
$('.b4').fadeIn(2000).animate({'right': '400px'}, 5000);
$('.b4').animate({'right': '400px'}, 5000).fadeIn(2000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `queue` of fadein like that :http://jsfiddle.net/h4e4cb80/

```
$('.b4').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 2000});
$('.b4').animate({'right': '400px'}, 5000);
```

**Queue** : A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: Solved. Ill tick in one minute.

Comment: interesting... either i misunderstood something, or this answer actually doesn't resolve it, at least not what has been asked... the moving still only happens after the fadein...

Comment: ah, think you need to remove the quotes (`'`) around `2000`, otherwise it's not working, at least it doesn't for me using your jsfiddle...

Comment: @webeno it was only the quotes.I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `opacity` in the animation instead:

```
$('.b4').animate({'right': '400px', opacity: 1}, 5000);
```

**EDIT**: this will only work if you want to do the animation using the same time, so this might not be the perfect answer for you.

Comment: Opacity is a 2 seconds fading in. animation is a 5 seconds effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try two animations without queing them

```
$(function () {
    $(".b4").animate({
       display: 'block'
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $(".b4").animate({
      right: '400px'
    }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
});
```

or opacity:

```
$(function () {
    $(".b4").animate({
       opacity: "1"
    }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
    $(".b4").animate({
      right: '400px'
    }, { duration: 5000, queue: false });
});
```

Comment: huh... this seems to be the solution, but for some reason whgen pasting code simply image is not shown. Could it be due to a syntax error? I'll check...

Comment: @artm lostsock (who disappeared in the meantime) wasn't correct, you don't need to put 1 inside quotes for `opacity`, check out my test: http://jsfiddle.net/rnphc8mg/